Constraints Fail when Using Input Variables in Drivers
I'm encountering an issue in Blender where constraints stop working properly when input variables are used in drivers. Here's the setup:
I have a camera and a cube (scaled to 0 on the Z so it looks like a plane) to represent the camera's focus point. The cube's scale is calculated using drivers so it matches the projected "size" of the camera. Additionally, I have constraints set up: "Copy Rotation" on the cube and "Track To" on the camera. This setup allows the cube to always face the camera, and the camera to track its movement. This way, the cube is a representation of what is being rendered by the camera.
Individually, both the drivers and the constraints work as intended. However, when I introduce ANY variables inside the drivers, the constraints fail to update correctly.
Video (you don't have to download it)
Blend file (1.1 MB)
Is there a workaround for this issue, or am I missing something in my setup? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Response:
I've "fixed" it. The problem was indeed a dependency loop, so I used an intermediary empty. Here is the link for the updated blend file (<1 MB).
What I did feels like a workaround, and I would prefer to have something cleaner. If you have any ideas on how to do this more efficiently, please share them with me.

did you check the log? you have a dependency loop. This might be the reason. Dependency cycle detected:
OBCamera_FocusPoint/TRANSFORM_CONSTRAINTS() depends on
OBCamera_FocusPoint/TRANSFORM_LOCAL() via 'ObBase-> Constraint Stack'
OBCamera_FocusPoint/TRANSFORM_INIT() via 'Transform Init'
OBCamera_FocusPoint/DRIVER(scale) via 'Driver -> Driven Property'
CACamera/PARAMETERS_EVAL() via 'RNA Target -> Driver'
CACamera/PARAMETERS_ENTRY() via 'Entry -> Eval'
....

Stupid question: what is the Copy Rotation constraint for on the cube, because you can rotate the camera, which will rotate the cube - but this rotation will not necessarily match the alignment of the camera, because that is determined by the Track Axis and the Up axis of the Track To constraint... Another stupid question: is there a specific reason to use a cube scaled to 0 on Z instead of a simple plane?

Hey @Gordon, I'm having trouble understanding your comment, especially this part: "but this rotation will not necessarily match the alignment of the camera, because that is determined by the Track Axis and the Up axis of the Track To constrain...". The rotation of the plane in the "fixed" version sometimes stops working, and I'm still trying to figure out why. Could you elaborate a bit on this, please? Also, I chose a Cube empty instead of a Plane because I would have to create a transparent material for the Plane. Ideally, Blender would have a Square empty like the Circle.

@David.Rodrigues If your goal is using the Copy Rotation constraint to align the cube with the camera, this doesn't work, for example: a camera with rotation (120°, -50°, -80°) is pointing straight forward to the cuboid because of a Track To constraint with that Target, and the constraint says the -Z direction should be directed to it and the camera's Y should be pointing upward: track to constraint. The rotation gets overwritten by the constraint. But the cuboid with Copy Rotation constraint gets rotated and is not aligned with the camera.

For the "square empty": why does it have to be an empty? Just so that it does not get rendered? You can also take a Curve > Rectangle with Fill Mode set to None, or use a Mesh > Plane, go into Edit Mode and with everything selected press X > Delete > Only Faces so that just the edges remain...

@Gordon, the Copy Rotation constraint does align the cube with the camera and the Track To constraint isn't overriding its rotation.
If you download the "fixed" version you can see that the effect that I'm going for is working.

The problems I currently have are: That I can't append that camera to an already created scene without it breaking, and I can't rotate the camera like in portrait mode (putting the camera in a vertical position while still tracking).

@David.Rodrigues "if you download the fixed version you can see that the effect [...] is working" - that might be true, but when I wrote the comment I was talking about the not fixed version and you asked me to explain it. My new comment to that was just that explanation, not meant to take the fixed version into account or resolving the current issue...
